# Devise: require token to register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I want to permit users to sign up *only* if they have a token. I'm thinking the `Confirmable` class might be able to help me there. Any ideas?

Maybe a single administrator can register and send confirmations to invitees email addresses? Is there a gem or module around that has achieved something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Use rails secure random to create invitations

```
Class Invitation
  belongs_to :user #if your system has users
  after_create :generate_token

  # Add migration
  # token :string
  # sent_out :boolean, default: false
  # used :boolean, default: false

  def generate_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.hex(13)
  end
end
```

Just pseudocode but one way of doing it. Track when they are sent/used. Do a lookup to see if they are valid.